# How to change Firefox preference default value?

Tags: firefox, proxy

I have problem with Firefox(31.0) on my Windows(7). I don't want that Firefox use system proxy, and for this issue, set "No proxy" in Options/Advanced/Network/Settings. But when I close Firefox then open it, this option changed to "Use system proxy".
I do this config in "about:config" manually.(set '0' in network.proxy.type) But similarly when Firefox restarted, this value changed to '5'.

How can i set permanent config for this ?

Comment: This shouldn't happen.  Is this machine under your control or is it part of a corporate network?

Comment: Unfortunately This happens and cause of confusing. My PC is connected to network, but is not under control somethings like domain.

Comment: Have you had any trouble with viruses recently?  Some set the pref.js file to read only, or it can be corrupted.  Have a look at the properties of `C:\users\[userid]\appdata\roaming\mozilla\firefox\profiles\xxxxx.default\prefs.js` and see if it is read-only (after closing firefox)

Comment: Disable all addons and plugins. If dont work try [create new user](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that "Janus Proxy Configurator" make this crazy behavior. when i disable it, Firefox works well.